# How to make body width smaller than the width of the head and foot?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to make the width of the "body" smaller, while keeping the head and the foot untouched. This is what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=16in,marginparsep=2in,left=1in,right=1in,textwidth=10in}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{HEAD}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
BODY
\end{document}
```

I expect the `"BODY"` to start much more *to the right* than the `"HEAD"`.

I want to have a 1in-horizontal-space before the header (that's why `left=1in`), and 3in space before the body (that's why `marginparsep=2in`). Now I have 1in in front of both of them. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the other way around: you make the head larger.

[image: x]

[image: z]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{paperwidth=16in,left=3in,right=3in, marginparwidth=2in, marginparsep=0in}

\usepackage{showframe}% show margins

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\hspace*{-2in}LHEAD} % changed
\fancyhead[R]{RHEAD\hspace*{-2in}} % added
\setlength\parindent{0pt}   

\begin{document}    
    BODY
\end{document}
```